# How to map a key for "Show/Hide All Effects" in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I use Photoshop CC (2015, on mac) and I realized that blending effects do affect performance *badly*. I just found out that I can show or hide all effects using *Layer* > *Layer Style* > *Show All Effects*, however I wonder if there is any way to map a key on this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spend some time learning Photoshop, you'll soon enough stumble upon the "Edit > Keyboard shortcuts" menu. You can attach that and many other commands to key combinations.